# R Sqldf: Conditional insert a binary value

Tags: r, sqlite, insert, sqldf

I'm using the sqldf package in R. I have 2 data sets,

A complete list of students

A list of students who submitted an assignment. (there are missing students)

Full list:

```
Student1
Student2
Student3
Student4
Student5
```

Submitted list:

```
Student1
Student2
Student5
```

I want to add a column in the full list and enter 1 or 0 depending if the student has submitted the assignment. So the final full list will look like

```
Student1   1
Student2   1
Student3   0
Student4   0
Student5   1
```

What would be the R code and the sql (sqlite?) code to do this? (Both for clarification's sake)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to Submitted list which will have a value of 1. Then, both the tables can be joined using `dplyr` or `sqldf`. Lastly, 0 can be added in a column which indicates whether assignment was submitted or not in final table.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

full_list <- data.frame(x = c("Student1", "Student2", "Student3", "Student4", "Student5"))
submitted_list <- data.frame(x = c("Student1", "Student2", "Student5"))
setDT(submitted_list)

submitted_list <- submitted_list[, assin_completed := 1L]


# using dplyr
dt <- left_join(full_list, submitted_list, by = "x")

# or using sqldf
dt <- sqldf("select full_list.x, submitted_list.assin_completed from full_list left outer join submitted_list on full_list.x = submitted_list.x")

setDT(dt)
dt <- dt[is.na(assin_completed), assin_completed := 0L]
```

The final table `dt` will give your desired output.

```
          x assin_completed
1: Student1               1
2: Student2               1
3: Student3               0
4: Student4               0
5: Student5               1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### sqldf

**1) in** Using the inputs defined in the Note at the end:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select Student, (Student in SubmittedDF) Submitted from FullDF")
```

giving:

```
   Student Submitted
1 Student1         1
2 Student2         1
3 Student3         0
4 Student4         0
5 Student5         1
```

**2) left join/coalesce** An alternative is to define `Submitted1` to be like `SubmittedDF` but having a second column of 1's (named `Submitted`) and then left join the `FullDF` data frame to it replacing NULL values generated by the join with 0.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with Submitted1 as (select *, 1 Submitted from SubmittedDF)
  select Student, coalesce(Submitted, 0) Submitted 
  from FullDF left join Submitted1 using(Student)")
```

giving:

```
   Student Submitted
1 Student1         1
2 Student2         1
3 Student3         0
4 Student4         0
5 Student5         1
```

#### Plain R code

**3) %in%** Regarding plain R code (no packages) we can use `%in%` like this:

```
transform(FullDF, Submitted = (Student %in% SubmittedDF$Student) + 0)
```

giving:

```
   Student Submitted
1 Student1         1
2 Student2         1
3 Student3         0
4 Student4         0
5 Student5         1
```

**4) merge/replace** An alternative is to perform the left join using `merge` and then use `replace` to change the NAs produced by the join to 0.

```
Submitted1 <- cbind(SubmittedDF, Submitted = 1)
transform(merge(FullDF, Submitted1, all.x = TRUE), 
             Submitted = replace(Submitted, is.na(Submitted), 0))
```

**Note:** Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines1 <- "Student
Student1
Student2
Student3
Student4
Student5"

Lines2 <- "Student
Student1
Student2
Student5"

FullDF <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
SubmittedDF <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```